# Must be str, not ImmutableMultiDict - Python/Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm confused on this one because if I run my code outside of a function and use `print` instead of `return` I don't seem to have any issues.

I'm sending data from HTML to Flask via a form as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <h4>Search for Your Device</h4>
  <p>Enter the Asset Tag of the device - On the back sticker or in small print at the bottom of the lock screen.</p>
  <p><input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
```

I then take that input and make an API request to my Mobile Device Management server with the following function

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def homepage():
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            #API URL
            JSS_API = 'https://private_url.com'
            #Pre-Defined username and password
            username = 'username'
            password = 'password'

            #Ask User for the Asset tag
            asset_tag = request.form
            New_JSS_API = JSS_API + asset_tag

            #Disables Warnings about SSL
            requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

            JSS_Asset_Response = requests.get(New_JSS_API, auth=(username, password), verify=False, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})

            JSS_json = JSS_Asset_Response.json()

            email_dict = {}
            for item in JSS_json['mobile_devices']:
                email_dict["Stu_name".format(item)]=item['realname']
            #Can call the dictionary value by doing the following:
            stu_name = email_dict['Stu_name']
            return stu_name

        return render_template("index.html")
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

The error I receive is "must be str, not ImmutableMultiDict" however if run the function in my terminal replacing the `return stu_name` with `print(stu_name)` I get the result I'm looking for!

My goal is to input via the form and then return the student's full name back to the webpage!

Comment: Share the full traceback

Comment: @Dan the error is only returned to browser even with `app.run(debug=True)` in terminal I only receive a 200 response that my POST was successful but nothing about the python error happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose `request.form` is a `ImmutableMultiDict`, `JSS_API` is a string,so you can't append a `ImmutableMultiDict` to a string,that's why you got the error.

You can convert the `ImmutableMultiDict` to dict:

```
request.form.to_dict()
```

And then **debug your code**,get the form data,I used to use `request.form.to_dict().values()[0]` to get the json string.

Or

If you are using an `POST` method you can retrieve parameters like this:

```
username = request.form.getlist('username[]')
```

GET method,use this:

```
username = request.args.getlist('username[]')
```

See more details from [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data).

Comment: Thank you a million. I had no idea I couldn't append like I was doing. Fixed it already :)